# Define the bottom of each bar in a stacked bar graph

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, difference

I have a two-dimensional array `absolute_heights` of shape `(2, 6)`.  I'd like to define a new two-dimensional array `bottoms` of shape `(2, 6)` that holds `0` at each position `i` unless

1) The sign of `absolute_heights[0, i] - absolute_heights[1, i]` matches that of `absolute_heights[0, i]`, in which case `bottoms[0, i]` should be set to `absolute_heights[1, i]`.

2) #1 is false, in which case `bottoms[1, i]` should be set to `absolute_heights[0, i]`.

Below is a `for` loop that achieves this:

```
def _get_bottoms(absolute_heights):
    """Define the bottom of each bar in a stacked bar graph.

    Parameters
    ----------
    absolute_heights : np.array
      The absolute height of each bar.  Stacking of the bars is along
      the first axis of this array.

    Returns
    -------
    bottoms : np.array
      The absolute height of the bar in each stack that is closest to
      zero.

    """
    bottoms = np.zeros((2, 6))
    for i, diff in enumerate(absolute_heights[0, :] - absolute_heights[1, :]):
        if np.sign(diff) == np.sign(absolute_heights[0, i]):
            bottoms[0, i] = absolute_heights[1, i]
        else:
            bottoms[1, i] = absolute_heights[0, i]
    return bottoms
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this in `numpy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use boolean indexing to avoid the `for` loop:

```
def _get_bottoms(absolute_heights):
    bottoms = np.zeros((2,6))
    diff = absolute_heights[0, :] - absolute_heights[1, :]
    i = np.sign(diff) == np.sign(absolute_heights[0, :])
    bottoms[0, i] = absolute_heights[1, i]
    bottoms[1, ~i] = absolute_heights[0, ~i]
    return bottoms
```

In this function `i` is a boolean array indicating whether the signs match (essentially your `if` statement). Inverting the boolean values with `~i` gives the array for the `else` statement.

Comment: i made a mistake in the original question.  check out the update.

Comment: @dbliss: I've updated my answer accordingly. It gives the same answer as your function on a test array.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using np.where

```
b = np.where(np.sign(ah[0,:]) == np.sign(ah[0,:] - ah[1,:]), ah[1,:], 0.)
b2 = np.where(np.sign(ah[0,:]) != np.sign(ah[0,:] - ah[1,:]), ah[0,:], 0.)
np.vstack((b2,b))
```

Unlikely to be substantially faster than the one mentioned above, possibly - slightly more readable.

`np.where` takes an array of bool conditions and then uses the first argument (`ah[1,:]` above) if the condition is True else second argument(`ah[0,:]` above).